# Subir archivos de mas de 10MB con php a una base de datos

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando con un hosting windows de Godaddy.

La aplicación puede subir y tratar archivos no mayores a 2mb, pero archivos mayores a esto, trunca  el script  y me da este error

> "C:\php56\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exceeded configured
>   activity timeout"

Mi php .ini tiene estos parametros

> upload_max_filesize=64M
>
> post_max_size=64M
>
> max_execution_time = 10000
>
> max_input_time = 10000

ya verifique estos parametros en el php info y si estan

¿que podría ser lo que me este faltando  ?

Answer (score 0):

De pronto alguna restricción como esta dentro de tu PHP:

```
   if($_FILES["archivo"]["type"] == "application/pdf" 
      && $_FILES['archivo']['size'] <= 1048576)
   {
     ....
   }
```

***Donde***:

> 1048576 es = a 1mb

O depronto en tu **php.ini** ha de ser ingresado de alguna de estas formas:

En el sistema binario (bits y bytes) es así

> **KILOBYTE** = 1,024 = 2 A LA POTENCIA 10 (1024 bytes que es lo mas
>   próximo a 1000, kilo significa mil)
>
> **MEGABYTE** = 1,048,576 = 2 A LA POTENCIA 20 (1048476 bytes lo mas
>   proximo a 1,000,000, mega significa millon)

Además ya probaste con reiniciar los servicios del servidor?

Comment: Probablemente el problema esta en el tiempo de ejecución pero también cambie los valores y reinicie los servicios del servidor, pero aun me sigue mandando el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

revisa tu php ini

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

Comment: Estaría bien que explicaras por qué tu sugerencia soluciona el problema, tal y como está la pregunta aunque pueda ser útil no es todo lo útil que podría ser.